# core-plt download time out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graph, charts, core-plot

i am trying to download core-plot by following command
http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot

but its give me time out message...

i am following http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application tutorial

i hope anyone knows what should i do

Comment: Do you have the Mercurial client installed as per the instructions on the project site: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingMercurial ?  You'll need that before pulling down the latest version of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this lonk:`http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlotInstaller_0.2.2.zip&can=2&q=`
 and use:`http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list` to download anything related core-plot
or open terminal and paste the link: `hg clone http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot`

Comment: hg clone http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot i am using this but not able to get core-plot

Comment: Did you paste this link to the terminal ?

Comment: now i am trying for http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/detail?name=CorePlotInstaller_0.2.2.zip&can=2&q= i hope this will work for me

Comment: @Zubair do you think should i have to take care any thing else while install core plot sdk

Comment: not necessary. simply install it & use it as given instruction

Comment: The command to clone the repository should use https: like this: 
hg clone https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/ core-plot